# How do I set the Engine used by ExecJS to NodeJS?

Tags: python, node.js, cloudflare, execjs

I'm trying to use the following package: [https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/master/cfscrape/**init**.py](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/master/cfscrape/__init__.py)

I have the following test file:

```
import cfscrape
import sys
import execjs

who = sys.argv[1]
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper() 
print scraper.get(who).content
```

Which is outputting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 1, in import cfscrape File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/cfscrape/__init__.py", line 17, in EnvironmentError: Your Javascript runtime 'JavaScriptCore' is not supported due to security concerns. Please use Node.js, V8, or PyV8.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to change my JS_ENGINE from `JavaScriptCore` to `NodeJs`

Comment: Are you actually trying to scrape a page protected by cloudflare, or do you just want to scrape any old webpage?

Comment: Protected by cloudflare

Comment: Anyways, the package that detects your `JS_ENGINE` isn't `cfscrape` - it's `PyExecJS`, which appears to determine your `JS_ENGINE` by checking the environment variable `EXECJS_RUNTIME` (in it's `get_from_environment` function in this file: https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS/blob/master/execjs/__init__.py )